# Can't inject EntityManager to constructor in some circumstances

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm encountering some strange situation. I've definied a service and gived it EntityManager as an argument to Controller constructor. When I'm trying to get my service (which is constructor) in other constructor everything work's fine. But when I directly open constructor which is a service I see:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Webrama\PbsTreeBundle\Controller\PbsTreeController::__construct() must be an instance 
of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in 
C:\www\strefaurody\bb\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 2374 and defined in 
C:\www\strefaurody\bb\src\Webrama\PbsTreeBundle\Controller\PbsTreeController.php
 line 16
```

My services.yml looks like that:

```
services:
    pbs_tree_controller:
        class: Webrama\PbsTreeBundle\Controller\PbsTreeController
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

Constructor is also simple:

```
private $em;

        public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
        {
            $this->em = $entityManager;
        }
```

Strange that I'm invoking method from a service which is using this injected in constructor EntityManager instance with success:

```
public function genratePbsTree()
        {

            $conn = $this->em->getConnection();

            $sql = "SELECT id_child AS id, TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM path) AS path FROM pbs_node_to_node WHERE depth = 2";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            return $result;
        }
```

There is a routing YML as requested:

```
webrama_pbs_index:
    pattern:  /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: WebramaPbsTreeBundle:PbsTree:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
      page:  \d+

webrama_pbs_brand_edit:
    pattern: /edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: WebramaPbsTreeBundle:PbsTree:edit, id: '' }
    requirements:
      id:  \d+
    options:
          expose: true

webrama_pbs_producer_add:
    pattern: /add/producer
    defaults: { _controller: WebramaPbsTreeBundle:PbsTree:addProducer }

webrama_pbs_series_add:
    pattern: /add/series
    defaults: { _controller: WebramaPbsTreeBundle:PbsTree:addSeries }

webrama_pbs_brand_add:
    pattern: /add/brand
    defaults: { _controller: WebramaPbsTreeBundle:PbsTree:addBrand }
```

Comment: There is no closing quote in your YAML configuration, is this just a copy-paste mistake? Also can you post the routing configuration (just the line for this controller)?

Comment: It's copy-paste mistake. Maybe the problem is that i'm defining my controller as a service in YAML. When I'm requesting this controller directyl via GET it's not used as I service but controller so EntityManager is not injected. It's just a theory.

Comment: Yes that's why I wanted to see your YAML configuration. That's a classic mistake (that I do often) to configure services for your controller and then misconfigure the routing: the controllers is then not loaded as a service.

Comment: How can I fix it? Maybe you can answer me so I would be able to use EntityManager in Controller and Service too :) ? -- There is a YML from the beginnning.

Comment: BLAH BLAH BLAH. Now is the 3rd time I ask you to show your routing configuration to help you.

Comment: Done. You don't specified that you would like to see routing config...

Comment: Yes I did it rather explicitly in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "controller" notation in your routing configuration:

```
_controller: WebramaPbsTreeBundle:PbsTree:index
```

If you want to have "controller as service" you need to use the service name:

```
_controller: pbs_tree_controller:indexAction
```

Read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Thanks. Going to test it todays evening.